# Unable to save the attachment in specific folder after downloading it from email in java

Tags: java, email

In my below code, I want to download attachment from email and then wants to store in specific folder named as Attachment in C drive but rather than that it is getting store in downloads,my code is as follows

```
String attachFiles = "";
String saveDirectory = "C://Attachment//"; // Here I want to store my attachments
if (contentType.contains("multipart")) {
    Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
    int numberOfParts = multiPart.getCount();
    for (int partCount = 0; partCount < numberOfParts; partCount++) {
        MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(partCount);
        if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition())) {
            String fileName = part.getFileName();
            attachFiles += fileName + ", ";
            part.saveFile(saveDirectory + File.separator + fileName);
        } else {
            messageContent = part.getContent().toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: Your `saveDirectory` already contains a separator, you don't need to add yet another one.

Comment: there is no exception,it just get store in downloads,might be it is not able to find the correct path of required folder

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel...i am sorry but it didn't get your point, do u mean to say I should not use  again file separator while saving the file i.e in dis statement part.saveFile(saveDirectory + File.separator + fileName);

Answer (score 0):

Either one of

```
String saveDirectory = "C:\\Attachment";
String saveDirectory = "C:/Attachment";
```

And definitely filter fileName

```
fileName = fileName.replaceAll("[^\\w.-]", ""); // Or so, period still dubious.
if (fileName.isEmpty()) fileName = "x";
```